# VS Code - Run Debug Configuration for a console_script in module mode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

My `setup.py` has the following console_scripts as entry points:

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['script=myapp.app:do_something',
                            'script2=myapp.app:do_something2'],
    },
```

with the following structure

```
.
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── mod.py
│   ├── mod2.py
│   └── submodules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mod3.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

and app looking like

```
##my_app.app

def do_something():
  #do stuff
def do_something2():
  #do other stuff
```

How can I get VS code debug configuration to enter at these module attributes. I have this that can run the module if I use `if __name__ == "__main__": do_something()` but want seperate launch.json files depending on the console_scripts

```
##launch.json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Module",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "module": "myapp.app",
      "args": ["--hello world"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thought you might be able to do simlar with:

```
  "module": "myapp.app:do_something",
```

but alas:

```
No module named myapp.app:do_something
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to make this work. At minimum you need a separate module per entry point or have a single module that took a command-line argument that then chose which function to call.

Comment: It's always nice to know. Thank you

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @EricHansen yes, `launch.json` still has no concept of entry points. If you wanted to open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python we could consider adding such support.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a `launch.json` that worked for me to debug mkdocs plugins:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "module": "mkdocs",
            "args": ["serve"]
        }
    ]
}
```

It uses [`"console": "integratedTerminal",`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes).

mkdocs provides the `mkdocs` entry point that accepts several arguments such as `build` and `serve`. This `launch.json` allowed me to set a breakpoint in a mkdocs plugin python file and stop at that breakpoing after running the mkdocs build/serve process.